# Как удалить строки с одной таблице, id которых не найден в другой?

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть 2 таблицы. Пример передает мой случай, но сам выдуманный. Не задавайте логический вопросов по типу "а зачем удалять"
Список людей и список жанров музыки связанных по ключу:

Люди

```
id|Name|musicId
1 |Вася| 1
2 |Петя| 2
3 |Маша| 3
4 |Саша| 2
```

Музыка

```
id|Name 
1 |Рок   
2 |Поп   
3 |Рэп   
4 |Шансон
```

Мне надо удалить из таблицы музыки все жанры, которые не используются в таблице Люди.

Для поиска я использую такой запрос:

```
select * from Музыка m
left join Люди l on m.id = l.musicId
where l.musicId is null
```

он мне выдаст соответственно шансон. Удаление через join не работает(жалуется на синтаксис. База постгрес). В реальной базе надо удалить 100 строк из 150.

использовала NOT EXIST для получение вложенного запроса, чтобы от него сообразить удаление, но выдает все 150 строк, наверное тут ошибка какая-то на поверхности которую я не вижу:

```
select *
from Музыка m
where not exists 
(select l.musicId
FROM Люди l 
where m."Id" != l."musicId")
```

не хочу 100 строк удалять руками, подскажите пожалуйста как мне удалить строки, где не содержится musicId из таблицы Музыка?

Comment: *наверное тут ошибка какая-то на поверхности которую я не вижу* Угу. Надо просто перевести то, что написано, на русский язык, и прочитать (обязательно!!) вслух. И сразу станет понятно, что использован неправильный оператор.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
delete from Музыка 
where Музыка.id not in (select distinct musicID from Люди)
```

Comment: Фу... мало того что NOT IN - самый медленный вариант, так ещё и дополнительный тормоз - ненужная сортировка.

Comment: @Akina А как нужно - через `not exists`? И где здесь сортировка - это вы про `distinct`?

Comment: @CrazyElf 1. Поскольку записей в таблице Музыка заведомо и явно меньше - да. При наличии подходящих индексов можно и LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL - сервер почти наверняка построит тот же план. А вот что то же будет с WHERE NOT IN - далеко не факт. Хотя сильно зависит от версии сервера. 2. Конечно. Иначе как удалять дубликаты?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE
FROM Музыка m
WHERE m.id IN
(
 SELECT m.id 
 FROM Музыка m
 LEFT JOIN Люди l ON m.id = l.musicId
 WHERE l.musicId IS null
)
```

было запилено то, что не работало внутрь вот таким образом